# How to modify this command to pull multiple results from the database

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using this command to pull records from a database:

```
CompletionsModel student = new CompletionsModel();

        try
        {
            student = db.Completions.Where(p => p.UserId == UserId).Single();
        }...
```

The problem is that it's pulling (as you can probably tell) a single record, when I need to pull all the records with that UserId. Originally, I had the UserId set as the Primary Key, but that, of course, means that it has to be unique. That constraint restricts each user to a single completion record (which doesn't help much when users can complete 20-30 courses!)

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**
Replacing ToSingle() with ToList() results in the following error:

> 'Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'Blah.Models.CompletionsModel'.

Removing both and simply ending the command at ..==UserId) throws basically the same error, but instead just asks if I'm missing a cast somewhere.

EDIT 2: My view is below.

```
@model Blah.Models.CompletionsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Transcript";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>StudentModel</legend>

    <div class="display-field">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Course Title&nbsp&nbsp</th>
                <th>Course Code&nbsp&nbsp</th>
                <th>Completion Date&nbsp&nbsp</th>
            </tr>
            @try
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.PRD.CompletionsModel)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PRD.PRD_TIT)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PRD.PRD_NUM)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompletionDate)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                <p><font color="red" size="xlarge">No course completions found.</font></p>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, just replace `Single()` with `ToList()`:

```
var students = new List<CompletionsModel>();

try
{
    students = db.Completions.Where(p => p.UserId == UserId).ToList();
}
...
```

That'll retrieve all records with a matching UserId. Actually, if you expect multiple records, that call to `Single()` should be throwing an exception...

Comment: What if you remove that `.ToList()`? What will be the return value? Just curious.

Comment: @Rahul: It will return an `IQueryable<T>` which will read from the database (through the context) as you enumerate it.

Comment: @GrantWinney: Wrong; `IQueryable<T>` _is_ actual data.

Comment: @GrantWinney: No, but saying it "isn't data" is not quite correct.

Comment: ToList() throws an error: 'Cannot implicityly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Blah.Models.CompletionsModel>' to 'Blah.Models.CompletionsModel'.

Comment: @DanCallahan, I don't think you have tried the exact code posted in answer. You would have not received that error.

Comment: @Rahul You're right, my mistake. That being said, when I *did* use it all, I got this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Blah.Models.CompletionsModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Blah.Models.CompletionsModel'.

Comment: Being pretty new to MVC, I'm not sure what a Dictionary is. Is that the View?

Comment: I imagine the error is occurring in the view; I'll add that.

Comment: You have a view that expects a single item and you're trying to pass in a list. You are going to need to change the view quite a bit to make this make sense. (If you're using the MVC auto-generated views, you want the "List" one, not the "Edit" one.)

Comment: Well this is interesting. I've got my View displaying multiple results now (good!), but instead of displaying every result it gets, it's displaying the first result over and over again - once for every record in the database tied to the UserId. Thoughts?